# How to extract the vertices value of a polygon?

Tags: graphics, polygons

I developed a code where I can extract the vertices of the polygon with highest adjacent. These are the index values of each polygon:

```
{Polygon[{7, 1, 4, 9}], Polygon[{20, 19, 14, 15}], 
 Polygon[{11, 5, 1, 7}], Polygon[{9, 4, 3, 10}], 
 Polygon[{13, 2, 6, 16}], Polygon[{12, 6, 2, 5, 11}], 
 Polygon[{10, 3, 8, 17, 18}], Polygon[{15, 14, 16, 6, 12}], 
 Polygon[{8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 13}]}
```

From here, I can determine the the biggest polygon which is `Polygon[{8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 13}]`.

Now, I want to determine the values like 8, 3, 4, 1 from them. Please let me know, what is the code to extract those numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `First@Polygon[{8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 13}]`?

Comment: Odrisso, I see that you Accepted my answer. (Thanks.) Does that mean I correctly understood your question?  If so I think we can edit it for clarity and reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it difficult to understand this question but I shall assume you have a series of [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) expressions in a [`GraphicsComplex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsComplex.html).

```
v = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}};

gr = Graphics[GraphicsComplex[v, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}]]];
```

If you use [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html) you get the actual coordinates from `v`:

```
Normal[gr] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Graphics[{Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}]}]
> ```